# Facebook Pixel not working on iOS mobile (Wordpress/Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, mobile, woocommerce, facebook-pixel

I am using `Wordpress` (`v 5.3`) with `WooCommerce` (`v 3.8.1`). My facebook pixel registers events (ViewContent/InitiateCheckout/AddToCart/Purchase/etc.) on desktop, but doesn't register events on mobile (iOS). All my plugins and theme are up to date. For my theme, I am using `Youplay` (`v 3.7.4`).

In searching for an answer, I have noticed some people who have had problems with their theme obstructing `Facebook Pixel` from working on mobile - some people reported needing to comment out a line in `functions.php` - I am including my theme's `functions.php` incase anyone notices anything that might conflict with `Facebook Pixel` working on mobile (in the posts I found, nobody was using the same theme as me):

**functions.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Youplay functions and definitions
 *
 * @package Youplay
 */

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yp_setup' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'yp_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */
function yp_setup() {

    /*
     * Make theme available for translation.
     * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
     * If you're building a theme based on Youplay, use a find and replace
     * to change 'youplay' to the name of your theme in all the template files
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'youplay', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
     * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
     * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    // Add editor style support.
    add_editor_style();

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     *
     * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails
     */
    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'       => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'youplay' ),
        'primary-right' => esc_html__( 'Primary Right Menu', 'youplay' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
     * to output valid HTML5.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list', 'gallery', 'caption',
    ) );

    /*
     * Enable support for WooCommerce
     */
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

    // Add default image sizes
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('500x375', 500);
    add_image_size('500x375_crop', 500, 375, true);
    add_image_size('200x200', 200, 200, true);
    add_image_size('90x90', 90, 90, true);
    add_image_size('1440x900', 1440);
    add_image_size('1440x900_crop', 1440, 900, true);
    add_image_size('1920x1080', 1920);

    // Register the three useful image sizes for use in Add Media modal
    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'yp_custom_sizes' );
    if ( ! function_exists( 'yp_custom_sizes' ) ) :
    function yp_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
        return array_merge( $sizes, array(
            '500x375_crop' => esc_html__( 'Carousel Thumbnail (500x375 crop)', 'youplay' ),
            '500x375'   => esc_html__( 'Carousel Thumbnail (500x375)', 'youplay' ),
            '200x200'   => esc_html__( 'User Avatar (200x200 crop)', 'youplay' ),
            '90x90'     => esc_html__( 'User Small Avatar (90x90 crop)', 'youplay' ),
            '1440x900_crop' => esc_html__( '1440x900 crop', 'youplay' ),
            '1440x900'  => esc_html__( '1440x900', 'youplay' ),
            '1920x1080' => esc_html__( '1920x1080', 'youplay' ),
        ) );
    }
    endif;
}
endif; // yp_setup

/**
 * Set the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 */
if (!isset($content_width)) {
    $content_width = 1400;
}

/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'yp_widgets_init' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'yp_widgets_init' ) ) :
function yp_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Default Sidebar', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'WooCommerce Sidebar', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'woocommerce_sidebar',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Sidebar for WooCommerce Pages', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'BuddyPress Sidebar', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'buddypress_sidebar',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Sidebar for BuddyPress Pages', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'bbPress Sidebar', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'bbpress_sidebar',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Sidebar for bbPress Pages', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Matches Sidebar', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'matches_sidebar',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Sidebar for Matches Pages', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 1', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'footer_widgets_1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 1 Column', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 2', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'footer_widgets_2',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 2 Column', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 3', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'footer_widgets_3',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 3 Column', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 4', 'youplay' ),
        'id'            => 'footer_widgets_4',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets 4 Column', 'youplay' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side-block widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title block-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );
}
endif;


/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yp_scripts' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'yp_scripts' ) ) :
function yp_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'youplay', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', '3.7.4' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', '', '3.3.7' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific-popup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css', '', '1.1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flickity', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/flickity/dist/flickity.min.css', '', '2.2.0' );

    // deregister bbPress styles
    wp_deregister_style( 'bbp-default' );
    wp_register_style( 'bbp-default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bbpress-styles.css' );

    // theme style
    $theme_style = yp_opts('theme_style');
    $youplay_style_file = '';
    $youplay_style_version = '3.7.4';

    if ($theme_style === 'custom') {
        youplay_maybe_compile_scss();

        if ( function_exists('nk_theme') ) {
            $youplay_style_file = nk_theme()->get_compiled_css_url('youplay-custom.min.css');
            $youplay_style_version = nk_theme()->get_compiled_css_version('youplay-custom.min.css');
        }

        if (!$youplay_style_file) {
            $theme_style = 'dark';
        }
    }

    if($theme_style !== 'custom') {
        $youplay_style_file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/youplay-' . $theme_style . '.min.css';
    }

    wp_enqueue_style('youplay-' . $theme_style, $youplay_style_file, array(), $youplay_style_version);

    // rtl
    if(yp_opts('general_rtl')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'youplay-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/youplay-rtl.min.css', '', '3.7.4' );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/js/all.js', array(), '5.9.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'font-awesome-v4-shims', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/js/v4-shims.js', array('font-awesome'), '5.9.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded'), '3.0.6', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-countdown', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/jquery-countdown/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.2.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'moment-timezone', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js', array('moment'), '0.5.14', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'magnific-popup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', '', '1.1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flickity', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded'), '2.2.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'object-fit-images', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/object-fit-images/dist/ofi.min.js', '', '3.2.3', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jarallax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/jarallax/dist/jarallax.min.js', '', '1.10.7', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js', '', '0.6.30', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hexagon-progress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/HexagonProgress/jquery.hexagonprogress.min.js', '', '1.2.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'youplay', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/youplay.min.js', array('jquery', 'bootstrap', 'isotope', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-countdown', 'magnific-popup', 'flickity', 'object-fit-images', 'jarallax', 'hexagon-progress'), '3.7.4', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'youplay-wp', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/youplay-wp.min.js', array('jquery', 'youplay'), '3.7.4', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'youplay-cf7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/youplay-cf7.min.js', array('jquery', 'youplay'), '3.7.4', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'youplay-init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/youplay-init.min.js', array('jquery', 'youplay'), '3.7.4', true );

    $dataInit = array(
        'enableParallax' => yp_opts('general_parallax'),
        'enableFadeBetweenPages' => yp_opts('general_fade_between_pages') && yp_opts('general_preloader')
    );
    wp_localize_script('youplay-init', 'youplayInitOptions', $dataInit);

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }


    // Custom CSS
    ob_start();
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/head_styles.php';
    $custom_css = ob_get_clean();
    $custom_css = wp_kses( $custom_css, array( '\'', '\"' ) );
    $custom_css = str_replace( '&gt;' , '>' , $custom_css );
    wp_add_inline_style( 'youplay-' . $theme_style, $custom_css );

    // Custom JS
    wp_add_inline_script( 'youplay-init', yp_opts('general_custom_js') );
}
endif;


// Compile SCSS.
if (!function_exists('youplay_maybe_compile_scss')) :
    function youplay_maybe_compile_scss() {
        if ( yp_opts('theme_style') !== 'custom' || ! function_exists('nk_theme') ) {
            return;
        }

        $theme_colors_from = yp_opts('theme_colors_from') == 'light' ? 'light' : 'dark';
        $theme_main_color = yp_opts('theme_main_color');
        $theme_back_color = yp_opts('theme_back_color');
        $theme_back_grey_color = yp_opts('theme_back_grey_color');
        $theme_text_color = yp_opts('theme_text_color');
        $theme_primary_color = yp_opts('theme_primary_color');
        $theme_success_color = yp_opts('theme_success_color');
        $theme_info_color = yp_opts('theme_info_color');
        $theme_warning_color = yp_opts('theme_warning_color');
        $theme_danger_color = yp_opts('theme_danger_color');
        $theme_skew_size = yp_opts('theme_skew_size');
        $theme_navbar_height = yp_opts('theme_navbar_height');
        $theme_navbar_small_height = yp_opts('theme_navbar_small_height');
        $theme_banners_opacity = yp_opts('theme_banners_opacity') / 100;
        $theme_images_opacity = yp_opts('theme_images_opacity') / 100;
        $theme_images_hover_opacity = yp_opts('theme_images_hover_opacity') / 100;

        $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
        $theme_parent = $theme_data->parent();
        if (!empty($theme_parent)) {
            $theme_data = $theme_parent;
        }
        $theme_version = $theme_data['Version'];

        $path = get_template_directory() . '/assets/css/';
        $custom_vars = '
            @import "_helpers.scss";
            @import "_variables.scss";

            $theme_version:"' . $theme_version . '";

            $theme:' . $theme_colors_from . ';
            $main_color:' . $theme_main_color . ';
            $back_color:' . $theme_back_color . ';
            $back_darken_color:' . ($theme_colors_from == 'light' ? '#FFFFFF' : 'darken($back_color, 13)' ) . ';
            $back_grey_color:' . $theme_back_grey_color . ';
            $back_darken_grey_color: ' . ($theme_colors_from == 'light' ? 'lighten' : 'darken') . '($back_grey_color, 10);
            $text_color:' . $theme_text_color . ';
            $text_mute_color:  rgba($text_color, 0.5);
            $color_primary:' . $theme_primary_color . ';
            $color_success:' . $theme_success_color . ';
            $color_info:' . $theme_info_color . ';
            $color_warning:' . $theme_warning_color . ';
            $color_danger:' . $theme_danger_color . ';
            $skew_size:' . $theme_skew_size . 'deg;
            $banners_opacity:' . $theme_banners_opacity . ';
            $images_opacity:' . $theme_images_opacity . ';
            $images_hover_opacity:' . $theme_images_hover_opacity . ';
            $navbar-height:' . $theme_navbar_height . 'px;
            $navbar-sm-height:' . $theme_navbar_small_height . 'px;

            @import "_includes.scss"';

        nk_theme()->scss('youplay-custom.min.css', $path, $custom_vars);
    }
endif;
add_action('ot_after_theme_options_save', 'youplay_maybe_compile_scss');

/**
 * Admin References
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/admin/admin.php';

/**
 * Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/extras.php';

/**
 * Colors convert functions
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/colors.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Comments walker
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/comments-walker.php';

/**
 * Custom WooCommerce functions
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/functions.php';

/**
 * Custom BuddyPress functions
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/buddypress/functions.php';

/**
 * Custom bbPress functions
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/bbpress/functions.php';

/**
 * Infinitie Scroll for Posts
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/lib/nk-infinite-scroll/nk-infinitie-scroll.php';
```

I also found someone who said that their theme was removing a `WooCommerce` hook (I believe it was `woocommerce_after_single_product` but I am not exactly where I read that anymore) - I am not sure if my theme is doing that.

I have verified that all the `Facebook Pixel` events show up when I am not on mobile:
[image]

You can see that it is showing `Receiving activity` and has events listed. When I try on mobile, it say that it is not `Receiving activity` (there is a yellow dot), and it does not report the events.

I found the source code where the events are handled in `facebook-commerce-events-tracker.php`, maybe something in there isn't mobile friendly? I am showing only what I think may be relevant because I have no more room for text in this question:

**facebook-commerce-events-tracker.php**

```
...

class WC_Facebookcommerce_EventsTracker {
        private $pixel;
        private static $isEnabled = true;
        const FB_PRIORITY_HIGH    = 2;
        const FB_PRIORITY_LOW     = 11;

        public function __construct( $user_info ) {
            $this->pixel = new WC_Facebookcommerce_Pixel( $user_info );

            add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'apply_filters' ) );

            // Pixel Tracking Hooks
            add_action(
                'wp_head',
                array( $this, 'inject_base_pixel' )
            );
            add_action(
                'wp_footer',
                array( $this, 'inject_base_pixel_noscript' )
            );
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_after_single_product',
                array( $this, 'inject_view_content_event' ),
                self::FB_PRIORITY_HIGH
            );
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_after_shop_loop',
                array( $this, 'inject_view_category_event' )
            );
            add_action(
                'pre_get_posts',
                array( $this, 'inject_search_event' )
            );
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_after_cart',
                array( $this, 'inject_add_to_cart_redirect_event' )
            );
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_add_to_cart',
                array( $this, 'inject_add_to_cart_event' ),
                self::FB_PRIORITY_HIGH
            );
            add_action(
                'wc_ajax_fb_inject_add_to_cart_event',
                array( $this, 'inject_ajax_add_to_cart_event' ),
                self::FB_PRIORITY_HIGH
            );
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_after_checkout_form',
                array( $this, 'inject_initiate_checkout_event' )
            );
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_thankyou',
                array( $this, 'inject_gateway_purchase_event' ),
                self::FB_PRIORITY_HIGH
            );
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_payment_complete',
                array( $this, 'inject_purchase_event' ),
                self::FB_PRIORITY_HIGH
            );
            add_action(
                'wpcf7_contact_form',
                array( $this, 'inject_lead_event_hook' ),
                self::FB_PRIORITY_LOW
            );

        }

...

/**
         * Triggers ViewContent product pages
         */
        public function inject_view_content_event() {
            if ( ! self::$isEnabled ) {
                return;
            }
            global $post;
            $product      = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
            $content_type = 'product_group';
            if ( ! $product ) {
                return;
            }

            // if product is a variant, fire the pixel with content_type: product_group
            if ( WC_Facebookcommerce_Utils::is_variation_type( $product->get_type() ) ) {
                $content_type = 'product';
            }

            $content_ids = WC_Facebookcommerce_Utils::get_fb_content_ids( $product );
            $this->pixel->inject_event(
                'ViewContent',
                array(
                    'content_name' => $product->get_title(),
                    'content_ids'  => json_encode( $content_ids ),
                    'content_type' => $content_type,
                    'value'        => $product->get_price(),
                    'currency'     => get_woocommerce_currency(),
                )
            );
        }
```

Here is the `inject_event` function referenced above:

```
        /**
         * Preferred method to inject events in a page, normally you should use this
         * instead of WC_Facebookcommerce_Pixel::build_event()
         */
        public function inject_event( $event_name, $params, $method = 'track' ) {
            $code             = self::build_event( $event_name, $params, $method );
            $this->last_event = $event_name;

            if ( WC_Facebookcommerce_Utils::isWoocommerceIntegration() ) {
                WC_Facebookcommerce_Utils::wc_enqueue_js( $code );
            } else {
                printf(
                    '
<!-- Facebook Pixel Event Code -->
<script>
%s
</script>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Event Code -->
        ',
                    $code
                );
            }
        }
```

I noticed on mobile - the section that should have the `Facebook Pixel` code looks odd:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<noscript>
&lt;img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" alt="fbpx"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=549560325605747&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"/&gt;
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

**Above: Why is there an `img` element where the Facebook Pixel code should go?**

**EDIT:** For above question, it seems that it is the same for desktop so I don't think this matters - although I don't understand what it is.

I found where the actual event code is on my website when it gets injected - it looks like it is registering as a `PageView` though, and it should be `ViewContent` - maybe the categorization being wrong is somehow causing the issue (a conflict)?

```
<!-- WooCommerce Facebook Integration Begin -->

!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
<script>
fbq('init', 'xxxxx', {}, {
    "agent": "woocommerce-3.8.1-1.9.15"
});

fbq('track', 'PageView', {
    "source": "woocommerce",
    "version": "3.8.1",
    "pluginVersion": "1.9.15"
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery && jQuery(function($){
    $('body').on('added_to_cart', function(event) {
      // Ajax action.
      $.get('?wc-ajax=fb_inject_add_to_cart_event', function(data) {
        $('head').append(data);
      });
    });
  });
}, false);

</script>

<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- WooCommerce Facebook Integration end -->
```

This is what the same section looks like on desktop - I noticed it has an `em` attribute that is my email that isn't there on the mobile version - maybe this is important and needs to be included when the site is rendered on mobile?

```
fbq('init', 'xxxx', {
    "em": "myemail7@gmail.com"
}, {
    "agent": "woocommerce-3.8.1-1.9.15"
});

fbq('track', 'PageView', {
    "source": "woocommerce",
    "version": "3.8.1",
    "pluginVersion": "1.9.15"
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery && jQuery(function($){
    $('body').on('added_to_cart', function(event) {
      // Ajax action.
      $.get('?wc-ajax=fb_inject_add_to_cart_event', function(data) {
        $('head').append(data);
      });
    });
  });
}, false);
```

**EDIT:**For above, I learned that the email is there because I am a user of the site on my computer, but not on my phone - so I think that it is ok that my email isn't there for mobile. This is the code that creates the above code in `Facebook/WooCommerce` source code:

```
private function pixel_init_code() {
            $version_info = self::get_version_info();
            $agent_string = sprintf(
                '%s-%s-%s',
                $version_info['source'],
                $version_info['version'],
                $version_info['pluginVersion']
            );

            $params = array(
                'agent' => $agent_string,
            );

            return apply_filters(
                'facebook_woocommerce_pixel_init',
                sprintf(
                    "fbq('init', '%s', %s, %s);\n",
                    esc_js( self::get_pixel_id() ),
                    json_encode( $this->user_info, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT ),
                    json_encode( $params, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT )
                )
            );
        }
```

**EDIT**: I found where the `ViewContent` `Facebook Pixel` tracking code is - it is at the bottom of the page for both mobile and desktop and looks the same for both:

```
jQuery(function($) { 
/* WooCommerce Facebook Integration Event Tracking */
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
    "source": "woocommerce",
    "version": "3.8.1",
    "pluginVersion": "1.9.15",
    "content_name": "Accessory Power ENHANCE ENGXH10100BKEW GX-H1 Gaming Headset - Black, Blue",
    "content_ids": "[\"TFL-ENGXH10100BKEW-OPEN-BOX\"]",
    "content_type": "product_group",
    "value": "39.85",
    "currency": "USD"
});
 });
```

Neither event fires on mobile - both fire on desktop.

Why is my `Facebook Pixel` not working on mobile (iOS)? On my phone, I have tried both with `Safari` and `Chrome`.

**EDIT**
According to the comments I have seen throughout the source code, I believe it should be placing the `Facebook Pixel` event code in the `<footer>`, but it seems to be placing it in the `<head>` instead, would this matter for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, and it wasn't anything wrong with my code - apparently to receive the test events from my phone, I need to be logged into the facebook business manager on my phone or it won't work - and this issue isn't clearly stated really, on the `Test Events` page it says under the header at the top:

> Only events you trigger will display in the Test Events tool, not the
>   activity of other website users.

So you can see they weren't very clear about how to become the "you" in the above statement (you have to login to the business manager on the actual device you are testing on).